# Quarkus + kotlin dependency injection in tests

Tags: kotlin, testing, junit, dependency-injection, quarkus

I am working on my quarkus + kotlin application. Having class:

```
@ApplicationScoped
class ParrallerCronScheduler(private val someService: SomeService) : CronScheduler
```

When the application is running there is no problem, quarkus injects someService. However,
running this tests class:

```
@QuarkusTest
@QuarkusTestResource(PostgresResource::class)
internal class CroneUpdateTest(private val someService: SomeService): BaseIntegrationTest()
```

makes quarkus throw:
`When using constructor injection in a test, the only legal operation is to assign the constructor values to fields. Offending class is class com.tui.promotion_campaigns_service.services.impl.CroneUpdateTes`
which forces to use this imo ugly thing in tests:

```
@Inject
lateinit var someService: SomeService
```

Why the first way of test implementation not working? Is it possible to make it work?

I tried

```
class ParrallerCronScheduler @Inject constructor(private val someService: SomeService) : CronScheduler
```